# How to filter data based on items count in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an android chat app and I am trying to implement endless scrolling using Firebase Database in RecyrclerView using custom FirebaceRecyclerAdapter. For first messages load I get data from Firebase Database by using query that  ordering data by .orderByChild() and then .limitToFirst(specificCount) so far so good. But when user scrolled to the last visible item I have to get next portion of messages and the problem comes I did not get a straight way to get messages from Firebase Database after specificCount. I tried with that code:

```
  int startCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                FirebaseDatabase
                        .getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child(RequestParameters.FB_CHILD_MESSAGES)
                        .orderByChild(RequestParameters.FB_CHILD_MESSAGES_ORDERING_TIME)
                        .startAt(startCount)
                        .endAt(startCount + CustomFirebaceRecyclerAdapter.NEXT_MESSAGE_PORTION_COUNT)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

But after I read the documentation for .startAt() I realize how stupid is this. Anyone could help to make a query that gets items after `specificCount` and limit received messages to some count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I answered this less than a day ago, so I recommend scanning my answers. But I'll repeat.

The Firebase Database API is inherently not very well suited for pagination. Think of what happens when an item is inserted while the user is on page 1 (with the first ten items). They end up seeing the previous item 10 at the start of page 2, but will never have seen the newly inserted item.

That said, if you want to do pagination, it is technically possible. But instead of wanting to *skip* 10 items, you will instead have to tell Firebase to start the query at the last item from the previous page. This is called an anchor item and in code it looks like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child(RequestParameters.FB_CHILD_MESSAGES)
        .orderByChild(RequestParameters.FB_CHILD_MESSAGES_ORDERING_TIME)
        .startAt(timeOfLastItemOnPreviousPage, keyOfLastItemOnPreviousPage)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

The key properties here are:

- `timeOfLastItemOnPreviousPage`: the value of the `FB_CHILD_MESSAGES_ORDERING_TIME` property of the last item on the previous page
- `keyOfLastItemOnPreviousPage`, the key of the last item on the previous page (which is needed in case there are multiple items with the same value for `FB_CHILD_MESSAGES_ORDERING_TIME`

Comment: I think It would be fit perfect for me, I have another query that gets first 10 items and has onItemRangeInserted added and when user browsing older messages and new messages is recieved (added on position 0 in recyclerView) he will be noted by the listener.